# Why is there additional Space above a DialogFragment in Android 5?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

Consider this DialogFragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment

class TestDialog: DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_dialog, container)
    }
}
```

and the corresponding layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Dialog" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this on Android 5, there is additional Space in the Dialog above the "Test Dialog" String:

[image]

On Android 6 and above, there is no additional Space. Why does it appear on Android 5? Is this a bug in the support library for Android 5? Is there something I can do about it?

This issue does not appear for Dialogs created with

```
AlertDialog.Builder
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try add this `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` on 
`onCreateView()` ?

**Edit**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

I hope it will work with you

Comment: Could you please provide a more complete code snippet? DialogFragment doesn't define the method `getWindow()`.